# Continue function after page reload?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
function test() {
 console.log("Hi");
 setTimeout(function() {
  location.reload();
  console.log("Hi2");
 }, 1000);
}
test();
```

Hi everyone i wonder if there is any chance that i can continue function/save progress of a function? What do i exactly mean with that? Well look at the code above. As you can see i have simple console.log, after it i setup a timeout for 1 sec, and i am reloading a page. I'ts clear that the console.log after page reload won't work, and here is my question. Is it possible to run that console.log after page reload, without triggering this first console.log?

Comment: The second console log `Hi2` will never happen after location.reload()

Comment: Well i know that, that's why i am asking if there is any way i can save that page was reloaded, and launch the console.log inside a setTimeout without triggering the first one?

Comment: Why you need this, can you share the purpose, I  think localstorage can solve your problem

Comment: This is impossible, you would need a way to determine that the page was reloaded, e.g. change the URL parameter, and then run a function if a parameter was set, but it doesn't make sense to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way, I would have done it: using `localStorage`

```
localStorage.messages = [];   //define an array to store all your messages
localStroage.messages.push('Hi');
localStroage.messages.push('Hi 2');
// don't call that line more than once, otherwise it will wipe out existing data




function test() {
    check_messages();
    setTimeout(function() {
        location.reload();
        check_messages();
    }, 1000);
}

function check_messages() {
    if (localStorage.messages.length>0) {
         alert(localStorage.messages[0]); //display the message
         localStorage.messages.splice(0,1);  //get rid of it
    }

}

test();
```